# Can modern IDE detect field/method usage in subtree?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, ide, invocation

I often meet following problem:

I have following code:

```
void  rootMethod(){
    C c = method1(a,b);
    method2(c);
}
```

C looks like this:

```
class C{
   Type1 param1;
   Type2 param2;
}
```

I want to find all places where inside `method2`  and all methods are invoked in this method(recursively in deep)  uses `c.param1` field.

[image]

### UPDATE

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you `Ctrl-Alt-H` in eclipse. This is the closest option to what you need. Press this shortcut on your field and you will see all call hierarchies that Eclipse can see. Then select the root element in hierarchy, right click and choose "Copy Expanded Hierarchy". Paste this into text editor. Now search for `method2`.

Comment: I know this feature. but problem that target method can invokes in deep....  I try to draw. Please read update.

Comment: Often method2 has a lot of messed invokation

Comment: Copy Expanded Hierarchy - I should expand it on its own

Comment: There are 2 buttons in that view: "show caller hierarchy" and "show callee hierarchy". Play with them. As far as I see they can expand the tree automatically, so you will see the `method2` even if it is indirect caller.

Comment: I mean: press `Ctrl-alt-h`, the "Call Hierarchy" view will be opened. Take a look on the right-upper corner of this view. The view's toolbar should contain several buttons including those that I have mentioned.

Comment: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/08/05/57b/961/06d528969f618676d35f4e3b1da403c301684f3e.jpg

Comment: I tryed to play with all these buttons - all don't expand

Comment: Oh, my bad. This indeed expands one level only. BTW could you explain why do you need this? Probably other solution exists.

Comment: I have very messed business logic. I novice at this code. But I should to understand affection one parameter in request on another code

Answer (score 0):

The following is possible (only) in the just released IntelliJ IDEA 16 EAP:

- Invoke *Call Hierarchy* on `method2`
- Browse the hierarchy tree to show all methods you are interested in
- Invoke *Find Usages* on the `C.param1` field
- Edit the *Find Usages Settings* to *Include overloaded methods* and search in the Scope *Hierarchy 'Callees of method2'*

This will show everywhere in the hierarchy the `C.param1` field is used.